# mysql getting null values while joining 3 tables

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

when I try to get results from 3 tables, I only get info from 2, the third one returns only NULL values.
This is my query, I am running it in phpmyAdmin to test it out before putting it on server:

```
SELECT uk2.*,u.*,COALESCE(SUM(n.cost),'not found') as cost 
    FROM std13_k2_users AS uk2  
    JOIN std13_users AS u   
       ON uk2.userID=u.id   
    JOIN std13_k2_naklady AS n   
       ON uk2.userID=n.userID WHERE uk2.userID=986
```

I get values from all tables when the SUM is not NULL (there are no things to sum in that table). When it is NULL I only get values from std13_users table. The values from std13_k2_users are NULL.

My question is: how should I repair my query? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this please, assuming that your `joins` correctly done for your table schema.

```
SELECT uk2.*,u.*, case when SUM(COALESCE(n.cost,0)) = 0 then 'not found' 
else SUM(COALESCE(n.cost,0)) end as cost 
    FROM std13_k2_users AS uk2  
    JOIN std13_users AS u   
       ON uk2.userID=u.id   
    JOIN std13_k2_naklady AS n   
       ON uk2.userID=n.userID WHERE uk2.userID=986
```